# Controller lost model(autoloaded) instance after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

User model is added in autoload. And because jumping Contorller into another controller to change view like moving login to acitvation is not possible, I used redirect. But after redirect, user model's member values lost.

Login.php (Controller)

```
public function login_process()
{
  $post = array();
  $data = $this->input->post();
  $account = $data['email'];

  $result = $this->user->authenticate($account, $data['password']);

  if ($result) {
    $email = $this->user->email;

      if ($this->user->email_confirmation_validation($email)) {
        redirect('/login/form/');
      }
      else {
        redirect('/activation/email_validation_gate/);
      }
  }
  else {
    redirect('/login/big_login_gate');
  }

}
```

when calling **redirect('/activation/email_validation_gate/');,** user model's data lost.

```
class User extends CI_Model
{
  const COLLECTION = 'users';
  private $_mongo;
  private $_collection;
  private $_user;

  ....

  public function __get($attr)
  {
      if (empty($this->_user)) {
          var_dump($this->_user);
          return Null;
        }

        switch($attr) {
              case 'email':
                return $this->_user['email'];
          case 'last_name':
                return $this->_user['last_name'];
          case 'first_name':
                return $this->_user['first_name'];
          case 'password':
                return NULL;
          default:
                return (isset($this->_user[$attr])) ? $this->_user[$attr] : NULL;
          }
  }


  public function load_data($user_id)
  {
    //$id = new MongoId($user_id);
    $this->_user = $this->_collection->findOne(array('_id'=>$user_id));
    var_dump('Mongo : '.$this->_user);
  }
}
```

**load_data** is called by login, and save user info into _user. After redirect, User Model's all gone. even it's autoloaded.

Followin is User Model Dump - **var_dump($this->user);**

```
 array(8) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#28 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "5349f7acc69c40282b000029" } ["first_name"]=> string(9) "First Name" ["last_name"]=> string(3) "Last" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$Qd4aV95A/kAWmMgQg/rJZ.iLCBo10XQeTZ0JgWdhjsblgHc4kQYpG" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@test.com" ["birthday"]=> object(MongoDate)#29 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(336927600) ["usec"]=> int(0) } ["country"]=> string(2) "KR" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" }
```

After redirect.

```
object(User)#16 (3) { ["_mongo":"User":private]=> object(DBConnection)#19 (2) { ["connection"]=> object(MongoClient)#20 (4) { ["connected"]=> bool(true) ["status"]=> NULL ["server":protected]=> NULL ["persistent":protected]=> NULL } ["database"]=> object(MongoDB)#21 (2) { ["w"]=> int(1) ["wtimeout"]=> int(10000) } } ["_collection":"User":private]=> object(MongoCollection)#22 (2) { ["w"]=> int(1) ["wtimeout"]=> int(10000) } ["_user":"User":private]=> NULL }
```

As shown above, all data is gone after redirect.

Comment: I think you can add parameter at url, `redirect` just change your url, it doesn't pass parameter, even you have call this method, the `_user` variable not record when you call this method again.

Comment: I checked that User model keep _user info data before redirect and use this model globally. After redirect, _user is missing. It seems that gc works and remove instance, I guess.

Comment: I think you can add a get _user method at User Model, and pass this result as url parameter. Or record this data to db.

Comment: I use __get, so $this->user->email can access _user['email']. I updated my code. This data is already recorded. This User's objective is globally use to load data after logged in.

Comment: I found this `_user` variable is private, i think you dump this variable, it is strange. The private variable shouldn't direct output.

Comment: _user variable is accessed by __get() method. basically this works as using $this->user->email. It's PHP syntax. I updated dump. Before calling redirect, it works. But All data is gone after redirect.